# How to find which function is calling another function in C?

Tags: c, debugging

Let's say I have a function called `verify()` inside `verify.c` and it is used to evaluate a condition and print debug message if the check fails.

```
void verify(int expected)
{
    if (expected < 10) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Verification failed for %d\n", expected);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Now, I am adding this header file `verify.h` in various c files throughout SW package, and many functions from different c files are calling `verify()`. If the check fails, `verify()` will print out the error message but how do I exactly find out where it is happening (i.e. which file and which function is actually calling failed `verify()`)?

I want to find this during I compile my code and without using a debugger such as `gdb`.

Comment: you could change verify so that it takes an additional argument in the form of a string, then whenever you call it just pass the name of the function calling it as that string and have that printed as well.

Comment: You can also look at [GNU cflow](http://www.gnu.org/s/cflow/) if you are running Linux. It will diagram the function call chain within your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given verify.h declaring:

```
#define verify(e) verify_impl( (e), __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__ )
void verify_impl( int expected, const char* file, const char* fn, int line ) ;
```

And verify.c defining:

```
void verify_impl(int expected, const char* file, const char* fn, int line ) ; )
{
    if (expected < 10) 
    {
        fprintf( stderr,"Verification failed for %d at %s:%s(%d)\n",
                 expected, file, fn, line );
        abort();
    }
}
```

The when `verify(9) ;` is called from `foo()` at line 20 of bar.c for example, you will get:

```
Verification failed for 9 at bar.c:foo(20)
```

However a more generally useful assertion mechanism is possible.  Consider:

verify.h:

```
#define verify(e) verify_impl( (e), #e, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__ )
void verify_impl( int exp, const char* expression, 
                  const char* file, const char* fn, int line ) ;
```

verify.c

```
void verify_impl( int exp, const char* expression, 
                  const char* file, const char* fn, int line ) ; )
{
    if( !exp ) 
    {
        fprintf( stderr,"Verification that %s failed at from %s:%s(%d)\n",
                 expression, file, fn, line );
        abort();
    }
}
```

Then when `verify( x >= 10 ) ;` is called with `x == 9` from `foo()` at line 20 of bar.c for example, you will get the more useful:

```
Verification that x >= 10 failed at bar.c:foo(20)
```

Any Boolean expression can be verified rather than the hard coded `exp < 10`.  If you still need the original hard test, then you can define another macro in terms of the new more flexible one:

```
#define verify_notlessthan10( e ) verify( (e) >= 10 )
```

Note the inversion of the logic; you are verifying that the expression is *true*, and aborting when *false*.  The semantics being that of *assert*.

Comment: I'm not sure how much it matters, but: `verify(x < 10)` and `assert(x >= 10)` trigger on the same values of `x`. I can't help but feel that the `verify()` interface with an expression is going to cause confusion since the logic is backwards.  This is incipient in the original function, but I think it should be noted.   If the function was `abort_if()` or some such name instead of `verify()`, then it is OK as it stands.  This is probably at least as much aimed at the OP as at you, Clifford.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point, I must admit, that was an error in my part, but as you say it matches the original semantics.  Will change, with note.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using gcc, you should be able to use the [`__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__FUNCTION__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) preprocessor macros, and pass them to your `verify()` routine to issue more useful debugging messages.  As tadman points out in his comment, it might make sense to define a macro that acts as a wrapper for `verify()`, capturing the file, line, and function information before passing it to `verify()`.  Then, at the point of use, you only need to call the wrapper and pass in the `expected` argument, letting the preprocessor fill in the extra information while it's still available in context, then passing it all to your `verify()` function.

Comment: You'll need to wrap it in a macro that properly passes these arguments into the function, though. Once you're in the function the caller context is gone.

Comment: @tadman no you don’t if you take them as parameters. verify(\_\_LINE\_\_); will work.

Comment: @Jim Lewis Are you proposing changing debug print to `fprintf(stderr,"Verification failed for %d, %s, %s, %d\n", expected, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);`?
In that case, it will just print `verify.c` lines.

Adding a helper funciton `__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__` just before calling `verify()` from each caller function could be a solution, however, what if there are thousands of callers? Adding this line before each function is tiresome.

Comment: @Fredrik That's what I mean: `#define verify` as something that passes the right argument through to `verify_impl(line)`.

Comment: @Sedmaister:  I'm suggesting that you redefine verify() to take additional arguments for the file, function, and line number.   The trick is defining a wrapper macro so you can just call verify_wrapper(expected) and have the macro pass the file, line, and function parameters to verify(),  The trick is to make sure that the expansion of `__FILE__` etc. gets deferred to the point of use, not at the point of definition of the wrapper macro.   I will come back and add a tested example if I have time.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to modify the code like this:

```
void verify(int expected, char * str)
{
    if (expected < 10) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Verification failed for %d\n", expected);
        if(str) 
            fprintf(stderr, str);
        abort();
    }
}
```

With this approach, you'll need to modify all calls. A way to get around that is to rename the function to `verify_aux` or something, and then write this:

```
void verify(int expected)
{
    verify_aux(expected, NULL);
}
```

This way, you could change verify to verify_aux if you feel the need to do so at a particular point.